# GetDatabaseName:

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a problem when retrieving the names of existing databases:

```
<code>
        var connectionString = "mongodb://user:pw@localhost/admin";
        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var server = client.GetServer();
        var lst = server.GetDatabaseNames();
        lst.Dump(); -- this is in Linqpad
</code>
```

Linqpad reports:

```
<code>
  Command 'listDatabases' failed: need to login (response: { "errmsg" : "need to      login", "ok" : 0.0 })
```

The same error happens when omitting the database name in the connection string.
The same error happens when using in my c# application.

Could you please explain how to get that list?

Well, in the meantime a had a look at the documentation (which I should have done before, sorry) and found out that I had to use this function with a parameter providing the admin credentials.

OK. BUT the error message is confusing and should be something like: You must provide the admin credentials..............

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
   const string legalConnectionString = "mongodb://localhost/?safe=true";
 var productionMongoDatabase = MongoServer.Create(legalConnectionString ).GetDatabase(productionDb, new MongoCredentials("admin", "1111111", true));
```